# Кол-во точек в круге

Tags: java, алгоритм, геометрия

На вход принимается радиус(целое число). Нужно вычислить сколько точек входит в круг. Пример:[image]

В данном случае радиус равен 2. В круг с таким радиусом входит 13 точек

Comment: как задаются точки?

Comment: Если речь идет о подсчете всех целочисленных точек в круге, то последовательность правильных ответов - это https://oeis.org/A000328 и https://oeis.org/A057655

Comment: а что если центр окружности расположен не в начале координат?

Comment: @Александр Уласевич Если в целочисленной точке, то результат будет такой же

Answer (score 5):

Формула окружности известна: `x*x + y*y = r`.

Соответственно, если расстояние от точки до центра окружности равно радиусу или меньше, то данная точка лежит в круге:

*Псевдокод (по умолчанию центр окружности лежит в 0,0. Если нет, то нужно это отдельно учесть):*

```
bool checkInCircle(x, y, r){

    if (math.sqrt(x**2 + y**2) <= r ){
        return True;
        }
    }
```

Или, допустим, что точка - отдельный класс:

```
bool checkInCircle(point pt, int r){

    if (math.sqrt(pt.x**2 + pt.y**2) <= r ){
        return True;
        }
    }
```

Comment: На вход дан лишь радиус

Comment: @wan140 Не имеет значения. Координаты точек все равно известны.

Answer (score 3):

Как я понимаю, точки - строго с целочисленными координатами. Если так, то тупо (даю схему)

```
count = 0
for i = -r to r
    count = count + sqrt(r*r-i*i) * 2 + 1
next i
```

Под `sqrt` имеется в виду целочисленное извлечение квадратного корня, с округлением вниз.

Само собой, всё это оптимизируется (можно считать только от 0 до r), но это уже мелочи.

Comment: было бы здорово, если бы вы привели теорию к данному алгоритму. Откуда он взять и на чем основан

Comment: @ГеоргийЧеботарев Вы мне предлагаете процитировать теорему Пифагора?

Comment: в этом решение возможно используется теорема Пифогора, только чтобы ее тут ясно видеть - нужно быть тем еще математиком-теоретиком. Такое ощущение, что вы просто выдернули код откуда-то, и сами не понимаете как оно работает)

Comment: @ГеоргийЧеботарев согласен с вами. Код ни на чем не основанный, да ещё и не работающий.

Comment: Да, с формулой напахал. Поправил.

Comment: что даёт умножение на 2 и прибавление 1 ? я так полагаю это учитывает симметричные точки, но как ?

Comment: @ampawd В диапазоне от -X до +X включительно располагается 2*X+1 целых чисел.

Answer (score 2):

Это [задача Гаусса](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssCircleProblem.html) о количестве целочисленных точек в круге радиусом R с центром в начале координат. Явная формула неизвестна, только через сумму ряда

```
N(r) = 1 + 4 * Floor(r) + 4 * Sum({i=1..Floor(r)}:[Floor(Sqrt(r^2-i^2))])
```

Edit: по сути, Akina считает тем же методом

Comment: Да, через сумму ряда. Но решение Гаусса выражается через сумму совсем другого,  существенно более простого ряда.

Comment: @AnT "Более простой" ряд ведёт к квадратичному решению

Comment: А без этого и не обойтись. "Линейность" вашего решения - ложная. Она основывается на предположении об элементарности операции вычисления квадратного корня. А это не так.

Answer (score 2):

Разумный баланс между эффективностью и компактностью буквального алгоритма - это подход из ответа @Akina. Разумеется, имеет смысл использовать такой подход для подсчета точек только в половине круга, а далее аккуратно умножить результат на 2. (Аккуратно - значит помня о том, чтобы не посчитать пограничные точки дважды).

Однако и в буквальном алгоритме можно обойтись без тяжелых/нецелочисленных операций вроде вычисления квадратного корня, если генерировать ограничивающую окружность алгоритмом типа Брезенхэма-Мичнера.

Например, вот такое решение (сорри, на С) пользуется алгоритмом Мичнера для подсчета точек в одной четвертинке и последующего аккуратного (см. выше) умножения результата на 4. При этом для подсчета точек в четвертинке достаточно генерации лишь одной осьмушки дуги окружности (количество итераций цикла в коде ниже соответствует одной осьмушке окружности)

```
unsigned MichenerCircleCounter(int radius)
{
  int radius2 = radius * radius;

  int x = radius, y = 0;
  int d = 1 - radius;

  unsigned count = 0;

  while (x >= y)
  {
    bool is_inside = x * x + y * y <= radius2;
    unsigned add = (x - y + is_inside) * 2;
    if (add > 0)
      count += add - 1;

    d += d <= 0 ? 2 * ++y + 1 : 2 * (++y - --x) + 1;
  }

  return (count - radius - 1) * 4 + 1;
}
```

Флаг `is_inside`, я уверен, можно вычислять не тяжело "в лоб", как у меня, а эффективным инкрементальным способом, пользуясь свойствами алгоритма Мичнера.

---

Также по ссылке https://oeis.org/A057655 можно увидеть менее "буквальное" решение Гаусса

```
A(n) = 1 + 4 * ([n/1] - [n/3] + [n/5] - [n/7] + ...)
```

где `n` - это квадрат радиуса круга

```
unsigned GaussCircleCounter(unsigned radius)
{
  radius *= radius;

  unsigned count = 0;
  for (unsigned divisor = 1; divisor <= radius; divisor += 4)
  {
    count += radius / divisor;
    count -= radius / (divisor + 2);
  }

  return count * 4 + 1;
}
```