# Как ускорить код по вычислению количества точек с целочисленными координатами, попадающими в круг радиуса n?

Tags: python-3.x, инспекция-кода, геометрия

Задача:

> Вычислить количество точек с целочисленными координатами, попадающими в круг радиуса n.

Я её решил таким образом:

```
def points(n):
count = 0
for i in range(-n, n + 1):
    for j in range(-n, n + 1):
        if i * i + j * j <= n * n:
            count += 1
return count
```

Но этот код тормозит, и онлайн проверка выдаёт тайм аут. Как можно ускорить этот код? Может через библиотеки? В локальном IDE(PyCharm) он тоже притормаживает.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Кол-во точек в круге](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/862955/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%b2%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b5)

Comment: Надо не решить, надо оптимизировать.

Comment: По ссылке как раз хватает идей для оптимизации.

Comment: По ссылке есть упоминание алгоритма Мичнера, используя его сложность получится O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Код можно оптимизировать, например, выполнив тест по одной четверти круга, и умножив на два количество попавших точек (кроме тех что лежат на нулевой оси Х) для получения числа точек в полукруге, и умножив еще раз на два (кроме тех что лежат на нулевой оси У) для получения числа точек в круге.

Или же пойти с другой стороны, и выполнить тест по одной четверти круга, и если точка не на оси то увеличивать результат на 4, а если на оси, то на 2, а если в начале координат, то на 1.

Answer (score 0):

Решил как советовали алгоритмом Минчера.

```
def points(n):
n *= n
count = 0
divisor = 1
while divisor <= n:
    count += int(n / divisor)
    count -= int(n / (divisor + 2))
    divisor += 4
return count * 4 + 1
```

Comment: ??? Это НЕ алгоритм Мичнера. Это решение Гаусса.

Comment: Ясно. Ошибся. Спасибо.